# compute dataframe operations on selected rows only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have time series based data.

```
time,val  
2018-04-25,30  
2018-04-26,10  
2018-04-27,-30  
2018-04-28,0  
2018-04-29,60
```

I need 4 columns to be added for:

```
 1. mean  
 2. average  
 3. (shifted)shifted val by 1  
 4. (diff)1 if val>0 else 0
```

In first go I calculate these as:

```
df['mean'] = df[val].ewm(span=3, adjust=False, ignore_na=False).mean()  
df['average'] = df[val].rolling(window=3, center=False).mean()
df['shifted'] = df[val].shift(1)
df['diff'] = 0
df['diff'][df['val']>0]=1
```

This is a large **dataset of millions** of rows. So I want each time I add a row to this, computation should happen for the **newly added row only.**
The columns that I have used are indicative of types of operations I apply on the actual data.
And the computation duration gap is in seconds. So **speed and performance matters.**

Is there a way to achieve this?